# Unable to conditionally cancel navigation requests for XAML Frame

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm currently trying to handle navigation in my WinUI3 app that's using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` for the UI. My situation is that I want to prompt the user that there are unsaved changes in the current page and let them decide whether to ignore changes and navigate to the requested page or stay on the current page.

```cs
public CompanyFormView() {
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) => {
        MainWindow.Window_MainFrame.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(NavigationRequest);
            ...
    };

    Unloaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) => {
        MainWindow.Window_MainFrame.Navigating -= new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(NavigationRequest);
    }; 
}
```

In the handler I have a ContentDialog that requires handler to be async. What happens is that I get the prompt from the ContentDialog, but the requested page is navigated to without respecting the async operation and therefore `e.Cancel` doesn't work as expected. I tried to comment out the await operation and then `e.Cancel` works so the issue should most likely have to do with the awaiting.

```cs
private async void NavigationRequest(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) {
    if (Model.IsCommitted)
        return;

    var updated = Model.GetUpdatedFields(GetFieldList());
    if (updated.Count == 0)
        return;

    bool stay = await PopUpDialog.UnsavedChanges(XamlRoot, updated);

    if (!leaveApproved) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? I'd prefer to handle it with a similar approach, but I'm open for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself with a bit different approach. The code-behind of the view will register for the `OnNavigationRequested` event that the navigation module of the app will invoke when the user has clicked an item in the sidebar of the app (XAML `NavigationViewItem`). The click event in the sidebar is handled by calling the navigation method to inform and then the event is invoked if there is a subscribing view. In general, whenever a new page is loaded, it subscribes to the event.

I'm not sure if this solution is the best, but I think it conforms quite ok to the MVP pattern. Also I read somewhere that event handlers should not return values but I can't see why it would be better to add another event or something  since it adds a lot more complexity in my opinion.

Anyway hope this helps someone out and if there's someone with more knowledge than me about what I've done please comment and point it out for helping others having the same issue.

```cs
// .xaml.cs file
public CompanyFormView() {
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) => {
        Navigation.OnNavigationRequested += NavigationRequest;
        ...
    };

    Unloaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) => {
        Navigation.OnNavigationRequested -= NavigationRequest;
    };
}

private async Task<bool> NavigationRequest() {
    if (Model.IsCommitted)
        return true;

    var updated = Model.GetUpdatedFields(GetFieldList());
    if (updated.Count == 0)
        return true;

    bool leaveAllowed = await PopUpDialog.UnsavedChanges(XamlRoot, updated);

    if (leaveAllowed) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```cs
// navigation file
public static async Task<bool> NavigationRequested(NavigationViewItem item) {
    if (item.Tag.ToString() == currentPage)
        return false; // since invoked is called for all clicks

    bool navigationApproved = await (OnNavigationRequested?.Invoke() ?? Task.FromResult(true));

    if (navigationApproved) {
        currentPage = item.Tag.ToString();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```cs
// view where the navigation attempt can be requested from
private async void SidebarMenu_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs e) {
    var item = e.InvokedItemContainer as NavigationViewItem
    if (item == null)
        return;

    bool approved = await Navigation.NavigationRequested(item);

    if (approved) { // doesn't seem to work!
        ((SidebarMenu.SelectedItem = item) as NavigationViewItem).IsSelected = true;
        Navigation.HandleRequest(item.Tag.ToString());
    }
}
```